# access fan and it's speed, in linux mint on acer predator helios 300

Tags: gpu, cpu, sensors, pwm, overheating

After booting my predator helios 300 to linux mint OS, I am unable to access my both the fans. How can I access them, as my system is heating up like crazy?

I used fancontrol module, but it is throwing error as:  pwm sensors not found. Now I am stuck,
I want to access my fans; how to do this?